# PHP + MYSQL. Чем раньше найдено совпадение в ячейке, тем выше в выводе результата

Tags: php, mysql, выборка

Возник такой вопрос. Есть возможность сделать так, чтобы чем раньше в ячейке было найдено совпадение, тем выше в выборке оно будет находиться. Например, сейчас вывод работает так: К примеру, ищем слово "провод"

```
1. Провод ПуГВ 1х6 Б (бухта) (м) РЭК-PRYSMIAN 0301070201
2. Беспроводной светильник полусфера 60 см, разноцветный
3. Гирлянда "Сеть" с контроллером 1.8х1.5м 180LED тепло-бел. прозр. провод 15Вт 220В IP20 NEON-NIGHT 215-135
4. Провод ПуГВ 1х6 Ч (бухта) (м) РЭК-PRYSMIAN 0301070101
5. Звонок проводной Сверчок трель регул. громкости 220В 80-90дБА бел. Тритон СВ-03Р
```

А необходим подобный результат:

```
1. Провод ПуГВ 1х6 Б (бухта) (м) РЭК-PRYSMIAN 0301070201
2. Провод ПуГВ 1х6 Ч (бухта) (м) РЭК-PRYSMIAN 0301070101
3. Беспроводной светильник полусфера 60 см, разноцветный
4. Звонок проводной Сверчок трель регул. громкости 220В 80-90дБА бел. Тритон СВ-03Р
5. Гирлянда "Сеть" с контроллером 1.8х1.5м 180LED тепло-бел. прозр. провод 15Вт 220В IP20 NEON-NIGHT 215-135
```

Т.е. чем раньше в ячейке было найдено слово "Провод", тем выше результат в выборке

Comment: А с чего Вы решили, что необходимый результат будет именно как `раньше найдено`? Почитайте как осуществляется поиск в БД по текстовым полям, что такое индексы, что такое полнотекстовый поиск, как работает `LIKE`.

Comment: Я не спросил, почему будет именно "как раньше найдено", я спросил, как такое можно реализовать и можно ли вообще

Comment: @Staringrad Из первого, что пришло на ум - сначала like + order by, далее работа с массивами/регулярками/строками или т.п. Мож кто более гуманный способ подскажет

Comment: можете попробовать найти [LOCATE](http://www.mysql.ru/docs/man/String_functions.html) и отсортировать уже по этому значению. Если не выйдет, то в php отсортировать массив по mb_strpos

Comment: Я потому и написал, "почитайте" - индексы для текстового поиска бывают разные и соответственно поиск по ним дает разные результаты - как минимум в быстродействии.

Comment: @phpBear "раньше найдено" это "позиция в строке".

Comment: @teran поверьте я понимаю о чем идет речь :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Надо использовать LOCATE или INSTR, например, так:

```
select ID, DESCRIPTION, INSTR(DESCRIPTION,'ле') `pos` from mp_placement
where DESCRIPTION like '%ле%'
order by INSTR(DESCRIPTION,'ле') asc
```